# How do I make zooming in/out on a webpage not distort my website layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I just started learning html and css last week, and im working on ym first website. I have been having trouble maintaning a fixed display. Whenever the zoom level on my webpage is less than 100%, all my elements are staying glued to the right side of the screen. When the zoom is more than 100%, all my elemnets are clumped togehter. Is there a way I can prevent this?

[When zoom is 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GXr2.png)
[When zoom is less than 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNK1N.png)

This is my code:

```css
#TopBar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1365px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgb(43, 123, 189);
}

#Logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
}

#Links {
  display: inline-block;
}

liv {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

liv:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border: none;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  padding-right: 13px;
}

liv:active {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#Log {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 265px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 27px;
}

#Log:hover {
  color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  transition: background-color, 0.1s;
}

#Log:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#Sign {
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

#Sign:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  transition: background-color, 0.1s;
}

#Sign:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#View {
  display: block;
  width: 1386px;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#Message {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

#MessageTitle {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#MessageParagraph {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#Join {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#Join:hover {
  color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 123, 189);
  transition: background-color, 0.1s;
}

#Join:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#code {
  top: 680px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 780px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#Selection {
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  left: 850px;
}

#SelectionTitle {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#SelectionParagraph {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#offers {
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#offers:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  transition: background-color, 0.1s;
}

#offset:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="TopBar">
    <p id="Logo"> Osolu </p>
    <ul id="Links">
      <liv><a>Tutor</a></liv>
      <liv><a>Contact</a></liv>
      <liv><a>Courses</a></liv>
      <liv><a>Finance</a></liv>
      <liv><a>Testing</a></liv>
      <liv><a>More</a></liv>
    </ul>
    <button id="Log">Log In</button>
    <button id="Sign">Sign Up</button>
  </div>

  <img src="https://www.digitalgravity.ae/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Web-Development.jpg" id="View" />

  <div id="Message">
    <p id="MessageTitle"> Achieve Success</p>
    <p id="MessageParagraph">
      With everything you child needs in one place to achieve success in their pursuit of computer science and technology, Osolu is the perfect place to them to master a variety of languages, learn important coding concepts, and dive deep into the expansive
      world of website development
    </p>
    <button id="Join"> Start Your Journey </button>
  </div>

  <img src="https://gowithcode.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/top-programming-languages.jpg" id="code">

  <div id="Selection">
    <p id="SelectionTitle">Explore a Variety</p>
    <p id="SelectionParagraph">
      With everything you child needs in one place to achieve success in their pursuit of computer science and technology, Osolu is the perfect place to them to master a variety of languages, learn important coding concepts, and dive deep into the expansive
      world of website development
    </p>
    <button id="offers"> See What We Offer</button>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Use `@media` rule of CSS .

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: When zoom is les than 100%, I want the navigation bar to stretch out.
I also want the width of my content to stay the same, but have white padding on both sides of the screen as the zoom keeps getting smaller. Its like the second photo I uploaded, except insteading of the right side being white, I want the left side to be white as well.

Comment: It seems you created your site on (or for) a 1366px wide laptop with all *fixed 'pixel' units*. First convert all your size properties to *relative units (rem, em, %, vw,vh,vmin,vmax)* before you even think of making your site responsive with `@media` queries. Elements that resize per device need a size value *relative* to another element or the browser viewport, *this is also true* for browser zoom in/out. E.g. `#TopBar { width: 80% }`  will be `1093px` on a 1366px laptop, but `1536px` on my 1920px desktop. Search online and read *responsive design 101* sites, after that dive into `@media`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your website becomes distorted upon zooming in or out is because of the varying screen size. You developed your website based on your screen size and device and did not make it dynamic to other screen sizes and devices. To solve this, you should use CSS media queries to make your website mobile-friendly and be able to run appropriately on different screen resolutions. Have a look here:

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Below is a simple template for some queries that might come in handy:

```
/* Mobile Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {}

/* Tablet Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {}

/* Desktop Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {}
```

If you want your website to be fully responsive, you will have to use more queries. A suggestion would be to not employ static units such as px for padding and margins given that other units such as `%`, `em`, or `rem` behave according to the screen size and are not constant such as px.